# mongod permission denied despite having permission

Tags: mongodb, file-permissions

I have a mongodb (ver4.2) installed on a GCP VM [Debian 10]. When I check 'systemctl status mongod' I get:

```
Nov 23 15:34:59 mongodbd4-vpc systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Nov 23 15:34:59 mongodbd4-vpc mongod.27017[5101]: 2021-11-23T15:34:59.751+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
Nov 23 15:34:59 mongodbd4-vpc mongod.27017[5101]: 2021-11-23T15:34:59.759+0000 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
Nov 23 15:34:59 mongodbd4-vpc mongod.27017[5101]: 2021-11-23T15:34:59.760+0000 I  ACCESS   [main] Error reading file /db/mongodb-keyfile: Permission denied
Nov 23 15:34:59 mongodbd4-vpc systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 23 15:34:59 mongodbd4-vpc systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is my ./etc/mongod.conf:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /db
  journal:
    enabled: true
  engine: wiredTiger
systemLog:
  destination: syslog
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  tls:
    mode: preferTLS
    certificateKeyFile: /certs/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /certs/ca.pem
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true
security:
  keyFile: /db/mongodb-keyfile
  authorization: enabled
```

This is my ls -al in /db:

```
drwxr--r--  2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Nov 23 15:37 journal
-rw-rw-r--  1 mongodb mongodb     5 Nov 23 15:37 mongod.lock
-r--------  1 mongodb mongodb  1004 Nov 23 15:02 mongodb-keyfile
-rw-r--r--  1 mongodb mongodb 36864 Nov 23 15:39 sizeStorer.wt
-rw-r--r--  1 mongodb mongodb   114 Nov 23 12:14 storage.bson
```

and for /certs:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mongodb mongodb 1338 Nov 23 12:06 ca.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 mongodb mongodb 5762 Nov 23 14:51 mongodb.pem
```

both folders have permission in themselves:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 mongodb mongodb  4096 Nov 23 14:51 certs
drw-rw-r--   4 mongodb mongodb  4096 Nov 23 15:40 db
```

Any idea why it sill fails with permission denied?

Comment: How do you start the mongod, i.e. which user?

Comment: I run 'systemctl start mongod' from the root user.

Comment: Which user runs the mongod process? Have a look at the service file

Comment: Maybe it is not the smartest way to put the key file into `dbPath` folder. I would prefer the mongodb users home folder.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Service file?

Comment: Run `systemctl show mongod -p FragmentPath` In this file you should find an entry `User=...`, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Comment: Do you run a ReplicaSet or a Sharded Cluster? `security.keyFile` is used for [internal authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-internal-authentication/), it has no effect on a stand-alone MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the problem was indeed the user running the process.
running from a non-root sudoer solved the problem.